# @OneToMany Mapping In HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql, one-to-many

I have this kind of situation. Imagine, I have class A and class B. relation between them is one to many. For example I have

```
// Class A
public class A {
    private Integer id;

    // some fields

    @OneToMany(name = "A_ID", targetEntity = B.class)
    private List<B> objectsB;

    // getters and setters
}

// CLass B

public class B {
   private Integer id;

   // some fields

   private Integer A_ID;
}
```

and I want to write HQL:
Query = ("select *someField* from A aEntity where aEntity.objectsB.id = :parameter " );

but because of mapping one to many A object contains list of B (objectsB) and aEntity.objectsB.id causes error. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't have a field `A_ID` in B. Either make the association unidirectional, and remove this field completely, or make the association bidirectional, and add a ManyToOne association from B to A.

Now, to answer your question, you need to learn about HQL joins:

```
select someField from A aEntity 
join aEntity.objectsB bEntity
where bEntity.id = :parameter
```

Comment: Thanks but I get MultipleBagFetchException. My query is : 
from A aEntity join aEntity.objectsB bEntity where aEntity.someParam LIKE '%:param1%' and bEntity.id := param2